# Json data not saving in django database Admin

Tags: python, json, django, django-views, geolocation

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to access user location through `geoplugin` BUT it was sending through `json` so i made a view to send `json` data to database BUT json data is not saving in `Database` (Admin).

When i click on link then it is showing :-

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'

BUT then i use `json.loads` then it is showing :-

> the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.JSONField()
```

views.py

```
def jsonLocation(request):
    r = request.POST.get('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp')

    # data = json.loads(r)

    data = r.json()

    for x in data:

        title = x["geoplugin_city"]
        user = request.user

        addin = Location.objects.create(city=title,user=request.user)

        addin.save()

    return HttpResponse("Successfully submitted!")
```

I have seen many answers but did't find any solution. And it is still not saving in database.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do in your view exactly? I don't think it does what you want it to do.

Comment: I am trying to save the output of the url. @dustin-we. Please Help

Comment: Do you want to make a POST-Request to the geoplugin.net url?

Comment: Yes Sir. I want to save the output from the url.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments on the post, this should be the error:

You are trying to make a POST-Request to the URL you provided us, doing the following:

```
def jsonLocation(request):
    r = request.POST.get('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp')
```

This will not work, `request`, is an object that describes the INCOMING request of the user loading YOUR webpage. This has a POST-property, from where you can get, e.g. form data.

To make a POST-request and save the data, you will need a Python package for it, I always use [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), I think it is also the most popular.

Then you would do something along the lines of this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp')

data = r.json()

# Continue your script
```

So, basically, your attempt was good, I think you just mixed up `request` and `requests`

Comment: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)